# Running an exe file with parameters in a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, parameters

I need to create a script that runs `setup.exe /configure Install.xml` from the folder the script is located.

When I run the script below, it does find the `setup.exe` but it does not read the parameters. It is like the last part (`/configure Install.xml`) is not being read.

**Script:**

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
strPath = "setup.exe /configure Install.xml ," & strFolder
objShell.Run strPath
```

Comment: Should be `strPath = strFolder & "\setup.exe /configure Install.xml"`

Comment: Should be an answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your code doesn't find and run the `setup.exe` in the script folder, but a different `setup.exe` somewhere in the `%PATH%`.

Simply appending the folder to the commandline is not going to do what you want. There are two ways for you to solve this issue:

- Run `setup.exe` with the full path, as suggested by [@AlexK.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041460/running-an-exe-file-with-parameters-in-a-vbs-script#comment67363424_40041460). You probably need to provide the full path to `Install.xml` too. Use the [`BuildPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method for constructing the paths. You may also want to add quotes around the paths to take care of spaces in them.

  ```
  Function qq(str) : qq = """" & str & """" : End Function

  strPath = qq(objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, "setup.exe")) & " /configure " & _
            qq(objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, "Install.xml"))
  objShell.Run strPath
  ```
- Change the working directory to the folder containing your script and `setup.exe` and run the command without path (or the relative path `.\setup.exe`).

  ```
  objShell.CurrentDirectory = strFolder
  strPath = "setup.exe /configure Install.xml"
  objShell.Run strPath
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I mixed it up and made this that works for me. (Not sure if something could be made cleaner, but it works!)

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
objShell.CurrentDirectory = strFolder
WshEnv("SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS") = 1 
WshShell.Run("setup.exe /Configure Install.xml"), 0, true 
WshEnv.Remove("SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS")
wscript.quit(RetVal)
```