# VBScript created by Indesign Extended Script, does not execute part of the code - WScript.Shell run

Tags: javascript, pdf, vbscript, adobe-indesign, odt

I have a VBScript that is created by Indesign JSX (Extended Script).
It runs a bash command (DOS) to convert an ODT to PDF.
However, via Indesign this part (shell.Run) does not work.
I put two MsgBox, one before and one after and both run.
Only the PDF conversion part that doesn't.

The VBS file is saved on the Desktop, if I run it by clicking on the file, it runs all the instructions.
The video serves to show that inside indesign it doesn't run, already in explorer, it works 100%.
https://youtu.be/0-O7KWVIOdo

Code JSX

```
    function fnc_ODT_RunVbsThroughJs(){
    //  community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/run-vbscript-through-javascript-in-illustrator/td-p/10082969
    var str = 
        'Set myApp = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")\r\n' + 
        'Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\r\n'+
        'Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")\r\n'+
        'MsgBox "Bem vindo seu Codorna"\r\n' + 
        'shell.Run  """C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4\\program\\swriter.exe"" --headless --convert-to pdf 4001278.odt"\r\n' +
        'MsgBox "Tchau seu Codorna"'
        ;

    var vbsFile = new File(Folder.desktop + '/codorna.vbs');

    try {
        vbsFile.open('w');
        vbsFile.write(str);

    } finally {
        vbsFile.close();
    }

    vbsFile.execute();
}
```

Code VBS

```
Set myApp = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox "Bem vindo seu Codorna"
shell.Run  """C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\swriter.exe"" --headless --convert-to pdf 4001278.odt"
MsgBox "Tchau seu Codorna"
```

**UPDATE 07/07/2022.**

I tried others Folders @Yuri Khristich.

I tried BAT, same problem... No... worse:

- by indesign or by clicking Windows explorer, do not work.
- by cmd: c:...\ODTtoPDF.bat works 100%

But don't tried notepad, I will. Only to see run a .exe file.

I need to convert ODT to PDF.

Apparently, the best to this is soffice or swriter.

Before, I tried to convert by word, but some files just crash in word, it don't happens with swriter.

**07/07/2022 Second round**

- @KJ, I tried your idea, nothing diferent happens :(, I renamed the Resource file, reopened Indesign with administrative privileges, the resource was reinstalled, but the problem continues

I removed the parameters and worked. Unfortunately I need the parameters to generate the pdf.

**Indesign JSX**

```
function fnc_ODT_RunVbsThroughJs(){
    //  community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/run-vbscript-through-javascript-in-illustrator/td-p/10082969
    var str = 
        'Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")\r\n'+
        'Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")\r\n'+
        'MsgBox "Bem vindo seu Codorna"\r\n' + 
        'shell.Run  """C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4\\program\\swriter.exe""" \r\n' +
        //'shell.Run  "C:\\PROGRA~2\\LIBREO~1\\program\\swriter.exe --headless --convert-to pdf 4001278.odt"\r\n' +
        //'shell.Run   "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"' 2022-07-07 NOTEPAD WORKS

        'MsgBox "Tchau seu Codorna"'
        ;

    //var vbsFile = new File(Folder.desktop + '/codorna.vbs');
    var vbsFile = new File(scriptFolder + '/codorna.vbs');

    try {
        vbsFile.open('w');
        vbsFile.write(str);

    } finally {
        vbsFile.close();
    }

    vbsFile.execute();
}
```

**VBS generated and run by Indesign (codorna.vbs)**

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox "Bem vindo seu Codorna"
shell.Run  """C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe""" 
MsgBox "Tchau seu Codorna"
```

Comment: I haven't tired it. Just a guess. Win10 has the paranoid mode by default. Perhaps it prevents from the launch vbs scripts this way. As far as I can remember sometimes to change the folder helps. Try to change `Folder.desktop` to `Folder.temp` or to any another location.

Comment: I have no the `swriter.exe` at hand. So I tried to launch `notepad.exe` instead. Your script works fine for me (it creates vbs, executes it, and opens Notepad) on Windows 7 and InDesign CS 6. If all you need is to run the command `swriter.exe --headless --convert-to ...` you could try to create cmd (bat) script instead of vbs and run it the same way via `execute()`.

Comment: I just tried it with Windows 10 and InDesign CS6 and it works as well (it opens notepad). So, probably it has nothing to do with Windows 10.

Comment: A stupid question... Have you tried to use a full path, something like: `d:\\temp\\4001278.odt` instead of `4001278.odt`?

Comment: Consdering the way of run parameters is the problem,
I will try others ways to run with parameters:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041460/running-an-exe-file-with-parameters-in-a-vbscript

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/87245987-a97e-4d6a-b563-3882608c4e88/vbscript-run-exe-with-parameters-on-a-network-share?forum=ITCG